# Media and Content catalog unavailable

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, content-editor-web-part, cewp

My enterprise has recently activated SharePoint online and I'm able to create sites and subsites. Unfortunately, when I try adding webparts to my page, I only get a handful of webpart catalogs :

[image: screenshot]

Notably, there is no `Media and Content` catalog, which I need in order to add content editor web parts, as well as script editor web parts.

What is the reason for this, and at what level can I fix it ?

Comment: You might lack of some permissions. Try logging in with site collection admin account :)

Answer (score 3):

Turn scripting capabilities on and off for SharePoint Online Tenant. It will enable\disable some features & webparts in SharePoint Online Tenant.

You can follow the below mentioned link to enable scripting.

[Enabling scripting capabilities](http://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000188451-prerequisite-1-enabling-scripting-capabilities)

After 24 hours you will get features & webparts in your SharePoint Online mentioned in below link.

[The new “Custom Script” (no-script) feature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sridhara/2015/04/02/the-new-custom-script-no-script-feature/)

Comment: My admin replied to me with a screenshot showing that scripting was already enabled. Is there anything else that can cause my site not to receive these features?

Comment: Not anything else but you need to wait till minimum 24 hours. after that you will get it

Comment: I have faced same issue before so i know it very well..

Comment: my admin says it was already enabled previously :(

Comment: It happens sometimes... Just turn off & on the feature again & it will work like a charm... You will find powershell script for the same by doing Google...

Answer (score 1):

You need to activate the publishing feature on the site collection

1. Site Actions > Site Settings >Site collection features > SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure
2. Site Actions > Site Settings >Manage site features >SharePoint Server Publishing

Please verify these and see if it works.